# Drupal 8 not getting installed with MAMP Pro and windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, drupal-8

I am using MAMP pro 4.1, I have successfully created host but whenever I try to install Drupal 8 it only creates about 13-14 tables and gets crashed.
On checking the MySQL logs I found

`[Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade`

I have also used Extras feature of MAMP Pro and Drupal 8 gets installed but it always include index.php in every URL like `drupal8/index.php/user/login` and always shows Page not found.

Version details:

`MySQL version: 5.7.24
Drupal version: drupal-8.7.2
PHP Version: 7.3.5 and 7.2.10`

Answer (score 2):

MySQL, MariaDB or Percona Server (Recommended).

Required MySQL 5.5.3/MariaDB 5.5.20/Percona Server 5.5.8 or higher with InnoDB as the primary storage engine, and requires the PDO database extension.

Note 1: MySQL 8 is supported only on Drupal 8.6 or higher, [see this](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2966523) issue.

Note 2: Drupal itself will generally operate with a default MySQL configuration. A more complex site will likely require configuration changes for the database. You can solve these common configuration issues using [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/259580).

[see this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/database-server)